# Rack::Cache not busting cache after changed etag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, rack, rack-cache

I have setup Rack::Cache to work with my rails application, heroku, Dalli and memcachd. Everything works as expected however when I update my content in the backend of my site the cache is still fresh. The etag is changed however this does not seem to bust Rack::Cache. How do I tell Rack::Cache to bust on content updates?